# [Updated:please review]Find the interesection point between an arc and a conical surface. (Actually, two parallel and concentric cones.)

Tags: differential-geometry

Update: What I believe I need to do (in laymans terms) is set the equation of the cone == the equation of the circle and solve; but to do that I first need to determine the equation of the circle, and get it into the same coordinate space as the cone equation.

Update2: I start with 4 dimensions. The sides of a rectangle, the length (on the diagonal) of that rectangle that separates the two limiting cones, and the radius of the arc:
[image: Inputs]

From there, the diagonal defines the large cone, the two smaller cones are at right angles to that.

Original post below.----------

I have two concentric, parallel conical surfaces -- ie. they share the same central axis and angle, but are at different displacements along that axis.

There is an arc, radius known, that is defined by its intersection with the two conical surfaces.

The centre of the arc lies in a plane that is tangent to another cone that is perpendicular to the first two and shares the same central axis, but who apex is in the opposite direction.

This image may or may not help:
[image]

The final piece of the puzzle is that the center of the arc lies radius units away, along a line, at a known angle, from the bisector of the line where the third cone intersects the first two.

How to calculate the end points that define the arc?

More importantly, how to frame this question in mathmatical terms such that the brains here might consider trying to help me with it.

[image: Showing extension of the cones to find intersection points]

Comment: What does concentric mean? What do you mean by arc?

Comment: Concentric cones -- share the same axis. Arc -- portion of a circle. Maybe the image above helps?

Comment: +1 for the beautiful diagrams.

Comment: Certain aspects of your description are problematic. Is the arc in this tangent plane, or just its center? What determines the endpoints of the arc (you just describe the circle, not what defines the desired arc of that circle)? If the center of the circle is a radius away from the bisector, then the circle is tangent to the bisector (assuming the circle is in the same plane), and thus can intersect it in only one point. So it cannot pass through the two points of intersection with the parallel cones.

Comment: The arc is in the tangent plane, as is all the construction required to determine its centre. See the top right image. The blue rectangle is the tangent plane, the solid black line (vertical) is the line of tangency between the larger (3rd) cone and the plane. The short dotted black line is at 35° to the centre point between the points of contact between the large cone and the other two. The longer dotted black line is the radius of the arc The points define the centre of the arc are those points where the arc insects (an extension of) the two parallel cones. See new image.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair I replied to your comment, but ran out of space so did not include your name, which I now learn is the only way you will be notified of my reply, so this is to ensure that happens. As you saw the ommision in my description, you at least understood it :)